# EMGD vs PSB_GFX GMA500 driver

Tags: acer, gma500

can anyone tell me which would be the better choice for my Acer Aspire One with Intel GMA500 video card? which would give me better graphic performance?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. Could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: shame this question was closed. It's broad and covers a large majority of netbooks released 1999-2012. The GMA graphics card had proprietary content inside it's drivers relating to the hardware-acceleration - a reason intel said why they can't have anyone looking at it's source code.
 Couple this with the issue of a mass-produced underpowered computer platform across almost every major brand, installed sometimes with Windows which was too slow, or unoptimised Linux flavours (for the above reason).
 Shame that "A specific moment in time" is used so aggressively by a select few moderators

Comment: 6 months before this question was closed by Daniele Napolitano, Ubuntu did release their PSB driver, so installing Ubuntu 12.04 or later will include the driver gma500_gfx without needing extra work. As EMGD uses proprietary code to enable hardware acceleration, that is cited as the preferred drivers for performance.

Answer (score 2):

PSB_GFX is not yet a fully functional driver. Think of it as a prototype that you should only install if you want to help test and develop it. Reportedly, it has good 2d acceleration, but lacks 3d, xv and hardware acceleration.

In case you are a regular netbook user, the choice should really be EMGD vs PSB, with the former working well on Lucid and Maverick, and the latter on Maverick and Natty.

Check out the Poulsbo page for more info:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo/

Comment: thanks. i was starting to get a bit confused because i have the emgd 1.8 driver installed and i saw alot of people were talking about this psb_gfx driver and i was wondering if i was using a outdated driver. i'm still new to this linux stuff. its only been a week since a switch from windows 7

Comment: Ouch. You've sure not picked the best piece of hardware to start using Linux with. Despite the fact that gma500 is an Intel chip, which usually entails decent Linux support, Intel has so far refused to provide a working driver, either open or closed source. In fact, Intel has been ignoring the problems its Linux customers had with gma500 for the past three years. Welcome to the club. :)

Comment: I've realized that when doing some research on getting Ubuntu on this net-book. if i had even know about Linux and Ubuntu at the time of buying a net-book i would have probably gotten one with more compatible hardware. just my luck to be stuck with a GMA500 card. hopefully my next PC (whenever i can afford one) will be alot more hardware compatible. besides i kinda like the challenge of having to word with this net-book. it forces me to do alot of research and learn alot about Linux. I've learn quite a bit this pass week